# Are there any JNDI Context implementations that are simple, meaning they can be started/stopped etc w/out leaking

Tags: java, jndi

I am not a particular fan of JNDI - i think its a bad technology when one wants to use OSGI for a number of reasons.

- JNDI is not self contained.
- Its too easy to leak and leave stuff in jndi.
- Its too easy to get conflicts because it is string based.
- JNDI is often a global thing with no scope - any one is putting stuff in providing there are no naming conflicts when binding.
- It should be socket less - sourcing objects from only a Map.

I would like to control the scope of a jndi context. I need it to use the Hornet JMS layer which unfortunately uses JNDI to register queues, topics etc. Rather than supply my own coded jndi context i would like to try and reuse another providing its scoped and not global.

Does anyone have any solutions/suggestions to solving this problem ?

Comment: are you talking about your own implementation for JNDI context?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a JNDI context implementation to solve this problem. You just need to code your resource acquisition and release correctly as in the rest of Java: basically, via `Context.close()` in `finally{}` blocks. Also make sure to close any `NamingEnumerations` you may have.

Comment: Unfortunately many libs want jndi themselves and id rather supply a socketless implementation that sources objects from something like a map which i can prepopulate.

Comment: If those libraries have resource leaks, complain to the supplier. I don't see how providing your own JNDI Context implementation can stop that.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleJNDI is an open-source implementation of JNDI which supports in-memory contexts, and can be populated from a tree of folders (sub-contexts) and properties/XML files (objects).

More info on the official website : http://code.google.com/p/osjava/wiki/SimpleJNDI (the documentation is inside the downloadable archive).

(P.S.: this is not an active project - the latest release being from 2010 - but it can help anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

I think Simple-JNDI could meet your requirement "providing its scoped and not global." You can configure it to produce shared or unshared contexts. In unshared mode every time you call

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext()
```

you get a unique in-memory copy of your context definition that only the calling code can see and modify.

To get more information about it go to https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI . It is an active project that is based on old osjava Simple-JNDI.